# How to get one to many relationship data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

These are two `tables` having `one-to-many` relationship:

```
Employee[Table]:
---------------------------------------------------
EmpId   | Name  | Country | Salary  | Email 
--------------------------------------------------
1         John    USA       875847   john@test.com
2         Mike    USA       785487   mike@test.com

Lincense[Table]
----------------------------------------
EmpId   | LicenseType   | LincenseNumber
----------------------------------------
1         LincenseType1   12345678
1         LincenseType2   87654321
1         LincenseType3   78945613
2         LincenseType1   12345678
2         LincenseType2   87654321
2         LincenseType3   78945613


EmployeeDetails[Expected ResulSet]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EmpId   | Name  | Country | LicenseType     | LicenseNumber | Salary    | Email
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         John    USA       LincenseType1         12345678    875847     john@test.com
                            LincenseType2         87654321
                            LincenseType3         78945613
2         Mike    USA       LincenseType1         12345678    785487     mike@test.com
                            LincenseType2         87654321
                            LincenseType3         78945613
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To get result in above expected format what would be the best way to achieve that so that result contain only one row for `Employee` detail and all associated `License` details?

Comment: A join. But you won’t get empty values for EmpId or Name, that you should handle in the presentation layer, not database.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, I tried join but that repeats Id, Name, Country, Salary and Email for all rows for specific user.

Comment: Yes, as I said that’s the job for presentation layer to handle. Not the database. It’s much easier there than trying to get the database to do it for you.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, Above is just an example. In real case there are hundreds of columns and thousands of row. This all data exported to excel and returning that much repeating data seems not feasible.

Comment: NOTE it's Licence or License, depending in what English you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here will do the trick for you. Remember if your empid and salary are `int` columns you can only `null` them or set 0 into it. Otherwise it need to be of type `string`

**SQL Code**

```
declare @emp table (empid int,[name] nvarchar(50),Country nvarchar(50),Salary int,[Email] nvarchar(50)
)
insert into @emp
values
(1         ,'John',   'USA',       875847,  'john@test.com'),
(2         ,'Mike',    'USA',      785487,   'mike@test.com')

declare @lic table (empid int, licensetype nvarchar(50),licencenumber int)
insert into @lic
values



(1         ,'LincenseType1',   12345678),
(1         ,'LincenseType2',   87654321),
(1         ,'LincenseType3',   78945613),
(2         ,'LincenseType1',   12345678),
(2         ,'LincenseType2',   87654321),
(2         ,'LincenseType3',   78945613)

select 
empid  = case when rn > 1 then null else x.empid end,
[name] = case when rn > 1 then '' else [name] end,
Country = case when rn > 1 then '' else country end,
licensetype = licensetype,
licencenumber = licencenumber,
Salary = case when rn > 1 then '' else Salary end,
Email = case when rn> 1 then '' else Email end

 from (
select a.empid,[name],country,licensetype,licencenumber,Salary,Email,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.empid order by licensetype) as rn from @emp  a left join @lic b on a.empid = b.empid
)x
```

**SQL Update**
If Lincencetype should always be 1 on first row you can just do it like this. This will be faster

```
select 
empid  = case when licensetype !='LincenseType1' then null else a.empid end,
[name] = case when licensetype !='LincenseType1'  then '' else [name] end,
Country = case when licensetype !='LincenseType1' then '' else country end,
licensetype = licensetype,
licencenumber = licencenumber,
Salary = case when licensetype !='LincenseType1'  then '' else Salary end,
Email = case when licensetype !='LincenseType1'  then '' else Email end


 from @emp  a inner join @lic b on a.empid = b.empid
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Working but taking much time to execute in actual scenario.

Comment: @JMD Yes it can be heavy. Inner join instead of left join btw.

Comment: @JMD look at my update. Dont know if you can use that rule, but that would be faster.

Comment: It that mandatory to declare tables there? Can't we do that directly without declaring table?

Comment: @JMD Yes just use your own tables. I just declared tables for test purpose

Comment: @JMD `SELECT somecode FROM EMPLOYEE(Table)  A INNER JOIN Lincense(Table) b ON a.EMPID = b.EMPID`

Comment: Working as expected.!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT Employee.EmpId, Employee.Name, Employee.Country,
       Lincense.LicenseType, Lincense.LincenseNumber,
       Employee.Salary, Employee.Email
  FROM Employee JOIN Lincense
       ON (Employee.EmpId = Lincense.EmpId);
```

If you are looking for empty values as you have shown, the best approach is to do that in your reporting tool rather than trying to do that in SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Employee.EmpId, Employee.Name, Employee.Country,
       Lincense.LicenseType, Lincense.LincenseNumber,
       Employee.Salary, Employee.Email
FROM Employee 
JOIN Lincense ON Employee.EmpId = Lincense.EmpId;
```

Will give you simmilar result but all rows will be filled with data.

```
SELECT Employee.EmpId, Employee.Name, Employee.Country,
       Lincense.LicenseType, Lincense.LincenseNumber,
       Employee.Salary, Employee.Email
FROM Employee 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lincense ON Employee.EmpId = Lincense.EmpId;
```

Will give you result for all employees, even if it has no licence, you will notice those rows by having nulls on Lincence's properties

```
SELECT Employee.EmpId, Employee.Name, Employee.Country,
       Lincense.LicenseType, Lincense.LincenseNumber,
       Employee.Salary, Employee.Email
FROM Employee 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Lincense ON Employee.EmpId = Lincense.EmpId;
```

Will give you result for all licences, even if employee is not present, you will notice those rows by having nulls on Employee's properties

If you need the empty rows, it's bad practice to do that in DB. Handle that in backend code once you obtain result. Or even only when displaying the result in front end.

**NOTE** it's Licence or License, depending in what English you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you want but close enough:

```
SELECT A.EMPID, A.NAME, A.COUNTRY, STUFF((SELECT ','+ b.LicenseType FROM License b WHERE A.EMPID = B.EMPID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS LicenseType, STUFF((SELECT ','+ C.LicenseNumber FROM License C WHERE A.EMPID = C.EMPID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS LicenseNumber, A.Salary, A.Email
FROM Employee A
```

It will not give you blank rows but will put LicenseType and LicenseNumber in same columns delimited by commas.